# I have jquery plugin for scale align but it is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter, scale

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="image-scale.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="gallery-lsit">
   <?php foreach ($gallery_imgs as $img):?> 
    <figure class="col-md-4">
        <a class="img-popup pan" data-fancybox="gallery" href="<?php echo base_url();?><?php echo $img->image_url; ?>">
            <img class="scale" data-scale="fill" src="<?php echo base_url(); echo $img->thumbnail_url; ?>" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
        <h3 class="text-center my-3"><?php echo $img->title; ?></h3>
    </figure>
   <?php endforeach;?>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("img.scale").imageScale();
});
</script>
```

As per the above code, I insert all required files in page but it is not working
In the below image you can see the current position of images on the page.
I want to show images in equal size.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check how many times your page have jquery